# Combining GPS and accelerometer data to increase location accuracy?

Tags: ios, gps, accelerometer

I'm trying to figure out a way to improve accuracy of my gps data. It's general purpose is navigation. My idea is to combine accelerometer and gps data, whilst I think this has been done before, I haven't been able to find good references. Is there a specific algorithm or practical approach I could use to achieve this, or does Apple perhaps provide an implementation with sensor fusion?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple already did that: The CLLocationManager property *desiredAccuracy* with value *kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation* will 
"Use the highest possible accuracy and combine it with additional sensor data. This level of accuracy is intended for use in navigation applications that require precise position information at all times and are intended to be used only while the device is plugged in."

Comment: Thanks, but I already knew about this setting, however it's not clear to me which sensors are actually being used and what the actual accuracy really is. Hypothetically speaking, polling the gps location based on a 5 meter filter and combining the gps with accelerometer data might be beneficial, but of course I'm just speculating.